# How can i set an element's id as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have some jQuery script in which I'm adding some rows to a table (when the user press a button). My problem is that I want to change the `id` of the elements inside the rows dynamically. I have set a global variable `i` which I set as an id to some elements inside my table. The problem is that after some debugging I found out that the `id` doesn't change at all and stays as the letter i (and not the variable `i` set to 0 and increase every time the user press the button). Any ideas?

```
var i=0;
var a1=i.toString().concat("1");
var a2=i.toString().concat("2");
var a3=i.toString().concat("3");
$("#table1").append("<tr><td><center><input id=\"a1\"></input></center></td><td>
center><button id=\"a2\">Load</button></center></td><td ><img id=\"a3\"></td>
</tr>");

$("#a2").click(function(){
   $z=$("#a1").val();
   $("#a3").attr("src",$z);
   i++;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#a3").attr("id", newId)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're writing those directly as strings. You need to concatenate them into the actual string. You can concatenate strings together using `+`.

```
$("#table1").append(
  "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + 
      "<center><input id=\"" + a1 + "\" /></center>" +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
      "<center><input id=\"" + a2 + "\" /></center>" +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
      "<center><input id=\"" + a3 + "\" /></center>" +
    "</td>" +
  "</tr>"
);
```

For what it's worth, the [`<center>` tag is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and should not be used. You may also consider creating some kind of template rather than generating your HTML as strings directly inside of JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you.it works fine.Still i cant understand why though;(

Comment: @Alator. Because writing a variables name in the middle of a string doesn't put it's value there. If it did, you would never be able to put the word "I" in a string if you already had a variable named "I" (or any other word combination). By concatenating the values together ("string" + variable) it appends the *value* of that variable to the end of that string.